# Is is possible to do mget with file patterns to only download certain files?

Tags: ftp, shell

I know we can do like mget *.xml which will download all xml files. But how is it possible that we using mget with certain file name patterns. can we do something like *SS.xml which mean it will download all files ending with SS.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `mget` command within FTP?

Yes, that should be possible, particularly if the remote server is a Unix server where file extensions have no special meaning on the server, they're just another part of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ncftp for the ftp client.  The user interface is friendlier and may have better wildcard support.  If you're trying to write a program to automate downloads, Expect is a programming language extension to TCL designed to automate interactive tasks.